# How can I have an armature deforming 2 separate meshes?

Tags: rigging

I have organized my model so that the skin is the parent of clothings, hair, etc. Currently all of them move together according to the parent hierarchy.

I select the skin and Ctrl+P to the armatures and selected automatic weight. In the pose mode it deforms only the skin because weight paint could not go to different object

If I Ctrl+J all of them the armatures would probably work, but can I keep the mesh organized and have the armature deform everything? I have different auto smooth settings for each groups for example, that I don't want to merge them.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok I got it. I have to select all of the meshes before selecting the armature the last. Blender will give all the vertex groups to every mesh with different weights and then I can paint them separately.